# How to insert copyright symbol in images in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS. I'm trying to insert a copyright symbol (c) into an image on my website. I tried using a decimal code, `&#169;`, in the following code, but it is displayed as it is. Can you help me how to fix that?

CSS:

```css
.image {
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
.image::after {
  content: "&#169; My Name"; 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  opacity: 0.9; 
  font-size: 0.7em; 
  color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175)}
  .image img {
    display: block;}
```

HTML:

```html
<span class="image">
   <img src="image1.png"/> 
</span>
```

This code shows `&#169; My Name` on my image instead of "© My Name".

Comment: hi, try using "\00a9 My Name" instead for the content property.
you can find a compelte list of characters here (if needed) : https://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/